# Error in performing aggregation (eg. sum, mean) with values_fn using pivot_wider() in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I have a data set which has the following format:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(tibble)
> 
> 
> data<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4),
+          Radius=c(5,5,5,5,10,10,15,15,10,10),
+          neighb_ID=c(1,11,2,12,3,4,7,8,3,4),
+          var_neighb=c(50,20,30,40,15,100,70,60,15,100))
> data
   ID1 Radius neighb_ID var_neighb
1    1      5         1         50
2    1      5        11         20
3    2      5         2         30
4    2      5        12         40
5    3     10         3         15
6    3     10         4        100
7    3     15         7         70
8    3     15         8         60
9    4     10         3         15
10   4     10         4        100
>
```

Now I want to pivot this data so as to aggregate `var_neighb` by `Radius` for each `ID`.
for example, for `sum` and `mean`, I wish to achieve the following table:

```
  ID1 Svar_neighb_Radius_5 Svar_neighb_Radius_10 Svar_neighb_Radius_15
1   1                   20                     0                     0
2   2                   40                     0                     0
3   3                    0                   100                   130
4   4                    0                    15                     0
  Mvar_neighb_Radius_5 Mvar_neighb_Radius_10 Mvar_neighb_Radius_15
1                   20                     0                     0
2                   40                     0                     0
3                    0                   100                    65
4                    0                    15                     0
>
```

I tried to do this using the following code:

```
> agdata<-data %>%
+    pivot_wider(
+     names_from = Radius, 
+     values_from = var_neighb,
+     values_fn = sum,
+     values_fill = 0
+     )
```

I only get the following error:

```
Error in values_fn[[value]] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
```

Additionally even if I take out `values_fn = sum,`, I get the following error:
`Error in values_fill[[value]] : subscript out of bounds`.

Can someone help me solve these issues so as to achieve my objective?

**EDIT**:
Sorry I overlooked an important requirement on the output table: the aggregation should be by `sum` and `mean` and should not include values of `var_neighb` for which `neighb_ID` equals `ID`. The output table `data_out` needs to have aggregation by `sum` and `mean`. So I have updated the `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values_fn` and `values_fill` should be named lists:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
  Radius=c(5,5,5,5,10,10,15,10,10),
  neighb_ID=c(1,11,2,12,3,4,7,3,4),
  var_neighb=c(50,20,30,40,15,100,70,15,100)
)

data %>%
  select(-neighb_ID) %>%
  pivot_wider(
     names_from = Radius, 
     values_from = var_neighb,
     values_fn = list(var_neighb = sum),
     values_fill = list(var_neighb = 0),
     names_prefix = "var_neighb_Radius_"
   )

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#       ID                var_neighb_Radius_5   var_neighb_Radius_10 var_neighb_Radius_15
#       <dbl>              <dbl>                <dbl>                <dbl>
# 1     1                  70                    0                    0
# 2     2                  70                    0                    0
# 3     3                   0                  115                   70
# 4     4                   0                  115                    0
```

**Update**
To remove values with `ID == neighb_ID` just use filter:

```r
data %>%
  filter(ID != neighb_ID) %>%
  select(-neighb_ID) %>%
  pivot_wider(
     names_from = Radius, 
     values_from = var_neighb,
     values_fn = list(var_neighb = sum),
     values_fill = list(var_neighb = 0),
     names_prefix = "var_neighb_Radius_"
   )
```

Not quite sure what You understand by "aggregation by `mean` as well as by `sum`" - You cannot do two different aggregations within single column, but You could just make two pivots and join them together:

```r
library(dplyr)

inner_join(
  data %>%
    filter(ID != neighb_ID) %>%
    select(-neighb_ID) %>%
    pivot_wider(
      names_from = Radius, 
      values_from = var_neighb,
      values_fn = list(var_neighb = sum),
      values_fill = list(var_neighb = 0),
      names_prefix = "var_neighb_Radius_sum_"
    ),
  data %>%
    filter(ID != neighb_ID) %>%
    select(-neighb_ID) %>%
    pivot_wider(
      names_from = Radius, 
      values_from = var_neighb,
      values_fn = list(var_neighb = mean),
      values_fill = list(var_neighb = 0),
      names_prefix = "var_neighb_Radius_mean_"
    ),
  by = "ID"
)
```

Comment: Hello @Linards, thanks for helping out on what I asked for. But I realized I over looked an important requirement on the aggregation and that is that the aggregation should not include values of ```var_neighb``` for which ```neighb_ID ```=``` ```ID```. Additionally, I need to have the aggregation by ```mean``` as well as by ```sum```. Are these possible in the block of code? I think I should edit the question, especially the required table?

Comment: Thank you @Linards. This is exactly what I wanted. And yes of course I was not expecting to do two different aggregations within a single column. I was thinking it was possible to do more than one aggregation in a single pivot without having rely on ```join```.